# Difference between JSON.parse and .json() in Javasscript

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a simple angular2 http get call like below

```
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
@Injectable()
export class ServiceBase {
  protected resource: string;
  constructor(private _http: Http) { }

  getTnCByCountryCodeNdType(countryCode: string, tncType: string) {
        let url = `${CONFIG.URL}/tnc?countryCode=${country}&tnc=${tnc}`;

        return this._http.get(url, this.getHeader())
                    .map((res: Response) => {
                        return res.json();
                    });
    }
}
```

The Error response from the above when received,

I tried

```
this.service
      .getTnCByCountryCodeNdType('MY', this.tnc.toLowerCase())
              .subscribe(x => {
                //
              },
              (err: Response) => {
                error = JSON.parse(err);
              });
```

where: err is the response error;

and it threw the usual json error .

> EXCEPTION: Unexpected token R in JSON at position 0

To my surprise

```
error = err.json();
```

Works fine. What is the difference between the two and why does the first one failed? Any help is appreciated

Comment: `err` is not defined or even declared in the code you've provided

Comment: @Quentin its an angular 2 service. Please i update code above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JSON.parse` is a JavaScript thing. It parses a string containing JSON into whatever that string represents. You don't pass it objects. Clearly, your `err` isn't a string.

The `res` and `err` that Angular 2's `http` gives you are [`Response`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/Response-class.html) objects, which says it derives from `Body`. I can't see anything in the Angular 2 docs saying what `Body` is, but clearly it has a `json` function that returns the result of parsing the response data as JSON. That's not a JavaScript thing, that's something from Angular. (As noted in the link above, it's inspired by — but not the same as — [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).)

Comment: Crowder thanks for the answer. Please i updated my code above.

Answer (score 2):

JSON.parse expects a JSON-formatted string, but you give it a Response object, which is not JSON, hence the parsing error.

res.json() extracts the JSON-formatted data from the Response object and converts the data into a JavaScript object.